# Mismo Código actua diferente PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una parte que uso en la versión pc y la versión móvil es igual pero no funciona bien en la segunda.

Esta es la versión PC, cuando pasa la hora de inicio de la clase + 30 minutos deja de aparecer el botón de reservar:

```
<?
$n_dia = date('N'); //dia de la semana
$n_hora = date('H') + (0.30);
//$n_dia = 7;
if ($n_dia == 7) {
    //si es domingo lo cambiamos a lunes para que pueda reservar
    $n_dia = 1;
    $n_hora = 7;
}

if (($n_dia <= $i) && $es_cliente) {

    if ($n_dia == $i && $clase_celda->int_hora <= $n_hora) {
        //ya no se puede reservar

    } else {

        if (!$reservas->estaReservada($clase_celda->id, $cliente->id_usuario, $inicio_de_semana)) {
            if ($reservadas >= $clase_celda->num_plazas) {?>
                <span style="color:red">CLASE COMPLETA</span>
        <?} else {
                if ($cliente->sesiones > 0) {?>
                    <a href="#TB_inline?height=150&inlineId=my-content-id-<?=$clase_celda->id?>" class="thickbox btn btn-default" style="width: 100%">
                       <i class="fa fa-circle-thin" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reservar
                    </a>

                    <div id="my-content-id-<?=$clase_celda->id?>" style="display:none;">
                            <form method="POST" action="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_clase" value="<?=$clase_celda->id?>"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="num_plazas" value="<?=$clase_celda->num_plazas?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="fecha_clase" value="<?=$dia['fecha_clase']?>"/>
                            <p>Está apunto de realizar la reserva de esta clase. Pulse en confirmar para completar la reserva.</p>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Confirmar Reserva</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>

              <?} else {?>
                    <p class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" style="width:100%">0 Sesiones disponibles</p><?
                }
            }
        } else {?>
            <p class="thickbox btn btn-danger" style="width: 100%"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reservada</p>
       ?}
    }
}?>
```

En cambio esta es igual pero no oculta el botón de reservar pasado el tiempo, puedo hacer reservas de cualquier día de la semana:

```
<?
$n_dia = date('N');//dia de la semana
$n_hora = date('H')+(0.3);
//$n_dia = 7;   

if($n_dia == 7){
    //si es domingo lo cambiamos a lunes para que pueda reservar
    $n_dia = 1;
    $n_hora = 7;
}   

if(($n_dia<=$i ) && $es_cliente  ){
    if($n_dia==$i && $clase_celda->int_hora <= $n_hora){
        //ya no se puede reservar
    } else {                                                

        if(!$reservas->estaReservada($clase_celda->id,$cliente->id_usuario,$inicio_de_semana)){                                 
            if($reservadas >= $clase_celda->num_plazas  ){ ?>

                <span style="color:red">CLASE COMPLETA</span>
          <?} else {
                if($cliente->sesiones>0){ ?>

                    <a href="#TB_inline?width=200&height=250&inlineId=my-content-id-<?=$clase_celda->id?>" class="thickbox btn btn-default" style="width: 100%" >
                       <i class="fa fa-circle-thin" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reservar
                    </a>

                    <div id="my-content-id-<?=$clase_celda->id?>" style="display:none;">
                            <form method="POST" action="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_clase" value="<?=$clase_celda->id?>"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="num_plazas" value="<?=$clase_celda->num_plazas?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="fecha_clase" value="<?=$dia['fecha_clase']?>"/>
                            <p>Está apunto de confirmar la reserva de esta clase. Pulse en confirmar para completar la reserva.</p>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Confirmar Reserva</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <? } else{ ?><p class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" style="width:100%">0 Sesiones disponibles</p>
              <?}
            }
        } else { ?>
            <p class="thickbox btn btn-danger" style="width: 100%"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reservada</p>
      <?}
    }
}
}
?>
```

Sabéis dónde puede estar el problema?

Llevo varios días con esto y no consigo solucionarlo, también intento hacer que si es menor a una fecha concreta (la caducidad de las clases del usuario) tampoco aparezca el botón.

Gracias

Comment: En el codigo de abajo, al final del todo, creo que te sobra un `}`. Espero que no sea por eso

Comment: Efectivamente, como dijo @TxemaAlment la unica diferencia que hay es que en el primero sobra un `}` de lo contrario ya entran en juego las variables que lo deben preceden, por ejemplo `$i` donde toma valor y que valor toma

Comment: No, no era esto, el `}` que sobraba era de líneas más arriba también tenía un `$i=1;` y `$i++;`